# PHP: How to read "Title" of font from .ttf file?

Tags: php, fonts, gd, truetype

I really need to be able to extract the metadata from a .ttf true type font file.

I'm building a central database of all the fonts all our designers use (they're forever swapping fonts via email to take over design elements, etc). I want to get all the fonts, some have silly names like 00001.ttf, so file name is no help, but I know the fonts have metadata, I need some way to extract that in PHP.

Then I can create a loop to look through the directories I've specified, get this data (and any other data I can get at the same time, and add it to a database.

I just really need help with the reading of this metadata part.

Comment: Interesting question, though the last person to ask this didn't get an answer :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564577/php-read-truetype-opentype-metadata-of-the-font-file

Comment: I was pretty sure you could get the font name using ImageMagick, but I can't seem to find any reference on the ImageMagick site. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Read TrueType/OpenType metadata of the font file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564577/php-read-truetype-opentype-metadata-of-the-font-file)

Comment: Maybe it was a duplicate candidate when it was posted 6 years ago, but the other question has no real answers other than a link pointing back to here. To close this because of the other one would be stupid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I came across [this link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3876-PHP-Extract-information-from-TrueType-font-files.html). It will do what you want (I've tested it and posted results). Just pass the class the path of the TTF file you want to parse the data out of. then use `$fontinfo[1].' '.$fontinfo[2]` for the name.

In case you don't want to register, here is the class

**Resulting Data**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Almonte Snow
    [2] => Regular
    [3] => RayLarabie: Almonte Snow: 2000
    [4] => Almonte Snow
    [5] => Version 2.000 2004
    [6] => AlmonteSnow
    [8] => Ray Larabie
    [9] => Ray Larabie
    [10] => Larabie Fonts is able to offer unique free fonts through the generous support of visitors to the site. Making fonts is my full-time job and every donation, in any amount, enables me to continue running the site and creating new fonts. If you would like to support Larabie Fonts visit www.larabiefonts.com for details.
    [11] => http://www.larabiefonts.com
    [12] => http://www.typodermic.com
)
```

**Usage**

```
<?php 
    include 'ttfInfo.class.php'; 
    $fontinfo = getFontInfo('c:\windows\fonts\_LDS_almosnow.ttf'); 
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($fontinfo); 
    echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

**ttfInfo.class.php**

```
<?php 
/** 
 * ttfInfo class 
 * Retrieve data stored in a TTF files 'name' table 
 * 
 * @original author Unknown 
 * found at http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2144.html 
 * 
 * @ported for used on http://www.nufont.com 
 * @author Jason Arencibia 
 * @version 0.2 
 * @copyright (c) 2006 GrayTap Media 
 * @website http://www.graytap.com 
 * @license GPL 2.0 
 * @access public 
 * 
 * @todo: Make it Retrieve additional information from other tables 
 *  
 */ 
class ttfInfo { 
    /** 
    * variable $_dirRestriction 
    * Restrict the resource pointer to this directory and above. 
    * Change to 1 for to allow the class to look outside of it current directory 
    * @protected 
    * @var int 
    */ 
    protected $_dirRestriction = 1; 
    /** 
    * variable $_dirRestriction 
    * Restrict the resource pointer to this directory and above. 
    * Change to 1 for nested directories 
    * @protected 
    * @var int 
    */ 
    protected $_recursive = 0; 

    /** 
    * variable $fontsdir 
    * This is to declare this variable as protected 
    * don't edit this!!! 
    * @protected 
    */ 
    protected $fontsdir; 
    /** 
    * variable $filename 
    * This is to declare this varable as protected 
    * don't edit this!!! 
    * @protected 
    */ 
    protected $filename; 

    /** 
    * function setFontFile() 
    * set the filename 
    * @public 
    * @param string $data the new value 
    * @return object reference to this 
    */ 
    public function setFontFile($data) 
    { 
        if ($this->_dirRestriction && preg_match('[\.\/|\.\.\/]', $data)) 
        { 
            $this->exitClass('Error: Directory restriction is enforced!'); 
        } 

        $this->filename = $data; 
        return $this; 
    } // public function setFontFile 

    /** 
    * function setFontsDir() 
    * set the Font Directory 
    * @public 
    * @param string $data the new value 
    * @return object referrence to this 
    */ 
    public function setFontsDir($data) 
    { 
        if ($this->_dirRestriction && preg_match('[\.\/|\.\.\/]', $data)) 
        { 
            $this->exitClass('Error: Directory restriction is enforced!'); 
        } 

        $this->fontsdir = $data; 
        return $this; 
    } // public function setFontsDir 

    /** 
    * function readFontsDir()  
    * @public 
    * @return information contained in the TTF 'name' table of all fonts in a directory. 
    */ 
    public function readFontsDir() 
    { 
        if (empty($this->fontsdir)) { $this->exitClass('Error: Fonts Directory has not been set with setFontsDir().'); } 
        if (empty($this->backupDir)){ $this->backupDir = $this->fontsdir; } 

        $this->array = array(); 
        $d = dir($this->fontsdir); 

        while (false !== ($e = $d->read())) 
        { 
            if($e != '.' && $e != '..') 
            { 
                $e = $this->fontsdir . $e; 
                if($this->_recursive && is_dir($e)) 
                { 
                    $this->setFontsDir($e); 
                    $this->array = array_merge($this->array, readFontsDir()); 
                } 
                else if ($this->is_ttf($e) === true) 
                { 
                    $this->setFontFile($e); 
                    $this->array[$e] = $this->getFontInfo(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if (!empty($this->backupDir)){ $this->fontsdir = $this->backupDir; } 

        $d->close(); 
        return $this; 
    } // public function readFontsDir 

    /** 
    * function setProtectedVar() 
    * @public 
    * @param string $var the new variable 
    * @param string $data the new value 
    * @return object reference to this 

    * DISABLED, NO REAL USE YET 

    public function setProtectedVar($var, $data) 
    { 
        if ($var == 'filename') 
        { 
            $this->setFontFile($data); 
        } else { 
            //if (isset($var) && !empty($data)) 
            $this->$var = $data; 
        } 
        return $this; 
    } 
    */ 
    /** 
    * function getFontInfo()  
    * @public 
    * @return information contained in the TTF 'name' table. 
    */ 
    public function getFontInfo() 
    { 
        $fd = fopen ($this->filename, "r"); 
        $this->text = fread ($fd, filesize($this->filename)); 
        fclose ($fd); 

        $number_of_tables = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[4]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[5])); 

        for ($i=0;$i<$number_of_tables;$i++) 
        { 
            $tag = $this->text[12+$i*16].$this->text[12+$i*16+1].$this->text[12+$i*16+2].$this->text[12+$i*16+3];

            if ($tag == 'name') 
            { 
                $this->ntOffset = hexdec( 
                    $this->dec2ord($this->text[12+$i*16+8]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[12+$i*16+8+1]). 
                    $this->dec2ord($this->text[12+$i*16+8+2]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[12+$i*16+8+3])); 

                $offset_storage_dec = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+4]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+5])); 
                $number_name_records_dec = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+2]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+3])); 
            } 
        } 

        $storage_dec = $offset_storage_dec + $this->ntOffset; 
        $storage_hex = strtoupper(dechex($storage_dec)); 

        for ($j=0;$j<$number_name_records_dec;$j++) 
        { 
            $platform_id_dec    = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+0]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+1])); 
            $name_id_dec        = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+6]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+7])); 
            $string_length_dec    = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+8]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+9])); 
            $string_offset_dec    = hexdec($this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+10]).$this->dec2ord($this->text[$this->ntOffset+6+$j*12+11])); 

            if (!empty($name_id_dec) and empty($font_tags[$name_id_dec])) 
            { 
                for($l=0;$l<$string_length_dec;$l++) 
                { 
                    if (ord($this->text[$storage_dec+$string_offset_dec+$l]) == '0') { continue; } 
                    else { $font_tags[$name_id_dec] .= ($this->text[$storage_dec+$string_offset_dec+$l]); } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        return $font_tags; 
    } // public function getFontInfo 

    /** 
    * function getCopyright()  
    * @public 
    * @return 'Copyright notice' contained in the TTF 'name' table at index 0 
    */ 
    public function getCopyright() 
    { 
        $this->info = $this->getFontInfo(); 
        return $this->info[0]; 
    } // public function getCopyright 

    /** 
    * function getFontFamily()  
    * @public 
    * @return 'Font Family name' contained in the TTF 'name' table at index 1 
    */ 
    public function getFontFamily() 
    { 
        $this->info = $this->getFontInfo(); 
        return $this->info[1]; 
    } // public function getFontFamily 

    /** 
    * function getFontSubFamily()  
    * @public 
    * @return 'Font Subfamily name' contained in the TTF 'name' table at index 2 
    */ 
    public function getFontSubFamily() 
    { 
        $this->info = $this->getFontInfo(); 
        return $this->info[2]; 
    } // public function getFontSubFamily 

    /** 
    * function getFontId()  
    * @public 
    * @return 'Unique font identifier' contained in the TTF 'name' table at index 3 
    */ 
    public function getFontId() 
    { 
        $this->info = $this->getFontInfo(); 
        return $this->info[3]; 
    } // public function getFontId 

    /** 
    * function getFullFontName()  
    * @public 
    * @return 'Full font name' contained in the TTF 'name' table at index 4 
    */ 
    public function getFullFontName() 
    { 
        $this->info = $this->getFontInfo(); 
        return $this->info[4]; 
    } // public function getFullFontName 

    /** 
    * function dec2ord() 
    * Used to lessen redundant calls to multiple functions. 
    * @protected 
    * @return object 
    */ 
    protected function dec2ord($dec) 
    { 
        return $this->dec2hex(ord($dec)); 
    } // protected function dec2ord 

    /** 
    * function dec2hex() 
    * private function to perform Hexadecimal to decimal with proper padding. 
    * @protected 
    * @return object 
    */ 
    protected function dec2hex($dec) 
    { 
        return str_repeat('0', 2-strlen(($hex=strtoupper(dechex($dec))))) . $hex; 
    } // protected function dec2hex 

    /** 
    * function dec2hex() 
    * private function to perform Hexadecimal to decimal with proper padding. 
    * @protected 
    * @return object 
    */ 
    protected function exitClass($message) 
    { 
        echo $message; 
        exit; 
    } // protected function dec2hex 

    /** 
    * function dec2hex() 
    * private helper function to test in the file in question is a ttf. 
    * @protected 
    * @return object 
    */ 
    protected function is_ttf($file) 
    { 
        $ext = explode('.', $file); 
        $ext = $ext[count($ext)-1]; 
        return preg_match("/ttf$/i",$ext) ? true : false; 
    } // protected function is_ttf 
} // class ttfInfo 

function getFontInfo($resource) 
{ 
    $ttfInfo = new ttfInfo; 
    $ttfInfo->setFontFile($resource); 
    return $ttfInfo->getFontInfo(); 
} 
?>
```

---

## Update 2021

Here is an updated version of the class with some fixes
https://github.com/HusamAamer/TTFInfo.git

Comment: I found a link which describes the header structures for the TTF format: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/fontnamefromfile.aspx

Comment: Did you mean to post this on the OP's post?

Comment: Not really. I meant to post something which provides some additional information to your answer. The class as posted obviously has implicit information about the file structure. The info I link explicitly defines the fields in the headers and discusses a few things about them. Dropping in classes is great, but a little extra understanding of the problem can also be helpful.

Comment: `$font_tags` is undefined in that code. Where is that variable suppose to be defined at? It isn't declared anywhere. How does this work for others?

Comment: how do i get the postscript name for the font

Comment: @Goose, Here is the fix. https://github.com/HusamAamer/TTFInfo.git

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-ids if you're looking for the full list

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to the previously posted answer... I've been using this class for a long time now.

```
class fontAttributes extends baseClass
{
    // --- ATTRIBUTES ---

    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fileName          = NULL ;                    //  Name of the truetype font file


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_copyright         = NULL ;                    //  Copyright


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fontFamily        = NULL ;                    //  Font Family


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fontSubFamily     = NULL ;                    //  Font SubFamily


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fontIdentifier    = NULL ;                    //  Font Unique Identifier


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fontName          = NULL ;                    //  Font Name


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_fontVersion       = NULL ;                    //  Font Version


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_postscriptName    = NULL ;                    //  Postscript Name


    /**
     *  @access private
     *  @var string
     */
    private $_trademark         = NULL ;                    //  Trademark



    // --- OPERATIONS ---

    private function _returnValue($inString)
    {
        if (ord($inString) == 0) {
            if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
                return mb_convert_encoding($inString,"UTF-8","UTF-16");
            } else {
                return str_replace(chr(00),'',$inString);
            }
        } else {
            return $inString;
        }
    }   //  function _returnValue()

    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getCopyright()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_copyright);
    }   //  function getCopyright()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getFontFamily()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_fontFamily);
    }   //  function getFontFamily()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getFontSubFamily()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_fontSubFamily);
    }   //  function getFontSubFamily()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getFontIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_fontIdentifier);
    }   //  function getFontIdentifier()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getFontName()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_fontName);
    }   //  function getFontName()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getFontVersion()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_fontVersion);
    }   //  function getFontVersion()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getPostscriptName()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_postscriptName);
    }   //  function getPostscriptName()


    /**
     *  @access public
     *  @return integer
     */
    public function getTrademark()
    {
        return $this->_returnValue($this->_trademark);
    }   //  function getTrademark()


    /**
     *  Convert a big-endian word or longword value to an integer
     *
     *  @access private
     *  @return integer
     */
    private function _UConvert($bytesValue,$byteCount)
    {
        $retVal = 0;
        $bytesLength = strlen($bytesValue);
        for ($i=0; $i < $bytesLength; $i++) {
            $tmpVal = ord($bytesValue{$i});
            $t = pow(256,($byteCount-$i-1));
            $retVal += $tmpVal*$t;
        }

        return $retVal;
    }   //  function UConvert()


    /**
     *  Convert a big-endian word value to an integer
     *
     *  @access private
     *  @return integer
     */
    private function _USHORT($stringValue) {
        return $this->_UConvert($stringValue,2);
    }


    /**
     *  Convert a big-endian word value to an integer
     *
     *  @access private
     *  @return integer
     */
    private function _ULONG($stringValue) {
        return $this->_UConvert($stringValue,4);
    }


    /**
     *  Read the Font Attributes
     *
     *  @access private
     *  @return integer
     */
    private function readFontAttributes() {
        $fontHandle = fopen($this->_fileName, "rb");

        //  Read the file header
        $TT_OFFSET_TABLE = fread($fontHandle, 12);

        $uMajorVersion  = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,0,2));
        $uMinorVersion  = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,2,2));
        $uNumOfTables   = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,4,2));
//      $uSearchRange   = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,6,2));
//      $uEntrySelector = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,8,2));
//      $uRangeShift    = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_OFFSET_TABLE,10,2));

        //  Check is this is a true type font and the version is 1.0
        if ($uMajorVersion != 1 || $uMinorVersion != 0) {
            fclose($fontHandle);
            throw new Exception($this->_fileName.' is not a Truetype font file') ;
        }

        //  Look for details of the name table
        $nameTableFound = false;
        for ($t=0; $t < $uNumOfTables; $t++) {
            $TT_TABLE_DIRECTORY = fread($fontHandle, 16);
            $szTag = substr($TT_TABLE_DIRECTORY,0,4);
            if (strtolower($szTag) == 'name') {
//              $uCheckSum  = $this->_ULONG(substr($TT_TABLE_DIRECTORY,4,4));
                $uOffset    = $this->_ULONG(substr($TT_TABLE_DIRECTORY,8,4));
//              $uLength    = $this->_ULONG(substr($TT_TABLE_DIRECTORY,12,4));
                $nameTableFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$nameTableFound) {
            fclose($fontHandle);
            throw new Exception('Can\'t find name table in '.$this->_fileName) ;
        }

        //  Set offset to the start of the name table
        fseek($fontHandle,$uOffset,SEEK_SET);

        $TT_NAME_TABLE_HEADER = fread($fontHandle, 6);

//      $uFSelector     = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_TABLE_HEADER,0,2));
        $uNRCount       = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_TABLE_HEADER,2,2));
        $uStorageOffset = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_TABLE_HEADER,4,2));

        $attributeCount = 0;
        for ($a=0; $a < $uNRCount; $a++) {
            $TT_NAME_RECORD = fread($fontHandle, 12);

            $uNameID = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,6,2));
            if ($uNameID <= 7) {
//              $uPlatformID    = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,0,2));
                $uEncodingID    = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,2,2));
//              $uLanguageID    = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,4,2));
                $uStringLength  = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,8,2));
                $uStringOffset  = $this->_USHORT(substr($TT_NAME_RECORD,10,2));

                if ($uStringLength > 0) {
                    $nPos = ftell($fontHandle);
                    fseek($fontHandle,$uOffset + $uStringOffset + $uStorageOffset,SEEK_SET);
                    $testValue = fread($fontHandle, $uStringLength);

                    if (trim($testValue) > '') {
                        switch ($uNameID) {
                            case 0  : if ($this->_copyright == NULL) {
                                        $this->_copyright = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 1  : if ($this->_fontFamily == NULL) {
                                        $this->_fontFamily = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 2  : if ($this->_fontSubFamily == NULL) {
                                        $this->_fontSubFamily = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 3  : if ($this->_fontIdentifier == NULL) {
                                        $this->_fontIdentifier = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 4  : if ($this->_fontName == NULL) {
                                        $this->_fontName = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 5  : if ($this->_fontVersion == NULL) {
                                        $this->_fontVersion = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 6  : if ($this->_postscriptName == NULL) {
                                        $this->_postscriptName = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                            case 7  : if ($this->_trademark == NULL) {
                                        $this->_trademark = $testValue;
                                        $attributeCount++;
                                      }
                                      break;
                        }
                    }
                    fseek($fontHandle,$nPos,SEEK_SET);
                }
            }
            if ($attributeCount > 7) {
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose($fontHandle);
        return true;
    }




    /**
     *  @access constructor
     *  @return void
     */
    function __construct($fileName='') {

        if ($fileName == '') {
            throw new Exception('Font File has not been specified') ;
        }

        $this->_fileName = $fileName;

        if (!file_exists($this->_fileName)) {
            throw new Exception($this->_fileName.' does not exist') ;
        } elseif (!is_readable($this->_fileName)) {
            throw new Exception($this->_fileName.' is not a readable file') ;
        }

        return $this->readFontAttributes();
    }   //  function constructor()


}   /* end of class fontAttributes */
```

Comment: How is this used? After you load the class in, which function do you call and what do you pass it?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use as is, but after changing some lines, I got it to work. An example of how to use this class after it's loaded would make this more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: missing baseClass? What is baseClass

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel when the fine people at DOMPDF project has already done the work for you? Take a look at php-font-lib @ https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib. This has all the features that you have asked for and supports other font formats as well. Look at the demo UI @ http://pxd.me/php-font-lib/www/font_explorer.html to get an idea about what kind of information you can get from this library.

Comment: That didn't exist when I asked this question. Although it probably is a better way of doing it now, the answer I used has served me well.

Comment: Hi, Dors! Would you, please, give me an example of how to use this library. The example page you supplied no longer exists. By the way, I voted you up since this library supports the font that I needed. The WOFF font.

Comment: @DrupalFever  the github page has a usage example right on the project page https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib .