# Java: How to read the properties of a font file?

Tags: java, file, fonts

I have an app where users are uploading fonts (TTF and OTF) and I'd like to sort them into regular, italic, bold, and bold-italic collections. Is there a way in Java to tell what style a font is?

Update: [this answer seems to be how to do it in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668901/php-how-to-read-title-of-font-from-ttf-file)

The following code says that 'HelveticaNeueLTW1G_Bd.otf' has a style of 'plain' but I would expect it to report it as a bold font.

```
File f = new File("/Volumes/Files/work/workspace/FontTest/src/com/opensoft/fonttest/", "HelveticaNeueLTW1G_Bd.otf");
System.out.println(f);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
Font createdFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
System.out.println(createdFont);
System.out.println(createdFont.getAttributes());
```

output

```
java.awt.Font[family=HelveticaNeueLTW1G-Bd,name=HelveticaNeueLTW1G-Bd,style=plain,size=1]
map of {family="HelveticaNeueLTW1G-Bd", weight=1.0*, width=1.0*, posture=0.0*, size=1.0, transform=null*, superscript=0*, tracking=0.0*[btx=null, ctx=null]}
```

thanks!

Comment: *"has a style of 'plain' but I would expect it to report it as a bold font."*  If you specify a `BOLD` variant of that `Font` does it become even more **bold**?

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah, I agree with you... It will become bolder...so ugly, I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure it out with straight Java but you can use the command-line tool [documented in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/is-there-a-unix-command-line-tool-that-can-analyze-font-files).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the problem here is that names and styles of fonts are distinct from the transformations (e.g. *italic* or **bold**) that can be applied at run-time via. `deriveFont`.  Effectively a font that is designed to be bold at the start, can become even more bold when the bold variant is used.

As a result of that, Java will simply report that default loaded variant of the font is 'not (using the) bold (variant)'.

Comment: I think fonts have to specify plain/italic/bold styles or else the program has to guess and perform that transformation itself. If this info is specified, maybe there is a way to sort by fonts that have a bold style, and have an italic style, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Font boldFont = createdFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);`. I am not sure it works if the bold style property is missing from a font.

Comment: I think that would set the style of any font to bold (even if it wasn't a bold font)

Comment: @KreeK Yeah, I believe so. Try to retrieve the font properties right after the method is called.

Comment: Yes it does now set the style to bold, but what I'm after is a way to tell if the font really is a bold font or not. Fonts that are not packaged will have four separate files for each style [regular, italic, bold, bold-italic] but other than the file name (which is often cryptic) I can't seem to find a way to tell the style.

Comment: @KreeK So, no way if the font is not tagged as bold in its metadata, I guess.